# DIV display priority - a slide show over a DD menu

Tags: html, css

I have a Drop Down menu and a slide show. I want my DD menu to be over the slide show, not the oposite.

I have tried z-index, but it didn't work.

Thanks.

EDIT: I solved it, z-index wasn't in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

That's a common one, I recommend you use Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug to inspect your element and see what css properties are being applied.

Another gotcha is that elements must have a CSS position. If an item has a `position` of `static` or no position is specified, it won't be affected by the `z-index`.